# Better ways of making a scroller

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/xkuZF/6/

```
function func() {
    document.body.scrollTop++;
}

window.onmouseover = function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
};

window.onmouseout = function() {
    interval = setInterval(func);
};

var interval =  setInterval(func);
```

Do you think that there are any better ways of doing this code?

Better:

- More options
- Less code

Comment: In the future, please avoid using pastebins. As stated in the [faq], it's much easier to review code when it's here, and your code is very short.

Comment: @Michael, you may have changed his original question which is to say about creating scroll bar manually.http://jsfiddle.net/xkuZF/6/

Comment: @didxga That is the only js code I found at that fiddle - what am I missing? If there's more code, would you suggest an edit?

Comment: No, he is talking about how you deleted the top 25% of my post...

Comment: @Michael, the <br>s thingy?

Answer (score 2):

To your questions:

- More options; sure you could provide a wait time to setInterval to control the speed of the scrolling down, you could also increase the scrollTop increment to make it scroll down faster.
- Less code; I think this is pretty much the bare minimum, a little too bare really.

I think `func` and `interval` are very generic names, I wasnt even sure if the code works / what it does until I clicked the fiddle link.

I would counter propose the following code, it is longer, but far more readable.

```
var scrollDownInterval;

function scrollDown() {
  document.body.scrollTop++;
}

function startScrollingDown(){
  scrollDownInterval = setInterval( scrollDown );
}

function stopScrollingDown(){
  clearInterval( scrollDownInterval );
}

window.onmouseover = function() {
  stopScrollingDown();
};

window.onmouseout = function() {
  startScrollingDown();
};

//Start scrolling down immediately
startScrollingDown();
```